# Taking ownership of ROAMING folder from another computer by connecting the HDD to an external hard drive

Tags: windows

Taking ownership of ROAMING folder from another computer by connecting the HDD to an external hard drive.

My old computer blew up, so I connected the HDD to my laptop. Now, the issue is that I don't have access to ROAMING and I can't get the password of some of my accounts. I thought it would be easy, but it seems almost impossible, which is dumb.

```
C:\Windows\system32>TAKEOWN /F E:\ /R /D Y
ERROR: The media is write protected.

C:\Windows\system32>ICACLS "E:\*" /reset /T
E:\$AV_ASW: The media is write protected.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

I also tried to do it with the security group, but I get similar message errors. Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find any tutorial for this specific situation.

Comment: did you verfied that your drive does not set to be write protected by diskpart?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just found the way.

https://www.lifewire.com/remove-write-protection-windows-10-8-7-4586905

Open diskpart.

```
Enter list disk

Enter select disk <disk number>

Enter attributes disk clear readonly
```

And then enter the command above:

```
C:\Windows\system32>TAKEOWN /F E:\ /R /D Y
ERROR: The media is write protected.

C:\Windows\system32>ICACLS "E:\*" /reset /T
E:\$AV_ASW: The media is write protected.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
```